# When installing a gem in a local project directory, how do I figure out what the proper gem file path should be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I'm using Ruby 2.6 and Rail 5.  I want to install the following gem

```
$ gem install ffi -v '1.9.18' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
Fetching ffi-1.9.18.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

but the above attempts to install it in a global location, and I would prefer to have this in my project directory, which I configured using

```
bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'
```

Per the documentation, I can add this to my "gem install" command

```
--local path_to_gem/filename.gem
```

but my question is what would "path_to_gem/filename.gem" need to be to properly install this ffi gem, or can I just make something up?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) and taking advantage of its [gemset](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) feature. Rails projects are not like Node projects where you would have a `node_modules` directory where all of your dependencies live. Instead, RVM would manage your dependencies locally and keep them separate using gemsets.